# How to write Javascript inside of Angular Binding?

Tags: javascript, angular

My code consists of img tag which fetches image dynamically.

```
<img src="{{'http://example.com/'+category.name+'.png'}}">
```

What I want to do is write Javascript code to replace `&` from the category name i.e.

```
<img src="{{'http://example.com/'+category.name.replace("&", "AND")+'.png'}}">
```

But Angular gives me the error when I write JS inside of the src binding. Please help me to fix this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using double quotos within double quotos try this -

```
<img src="{{'http://example.com/'+ category.name.replace('&', 'AND')+'.png'}}" />
```

Either you can bind this way too

```
<img [src]="'http://example.com/'+name.replace('&', 'AND')+'.png'" />
```

Comment: Damn you double quotes... Thanks a lot @PardeepJain! Worked Perfectly.

Comment: Stackoverflow wants me to wait 5 minutes before I can mark this as answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
<img [src]="createUrl()">
```

in the **.ts** file.

```
public createUrl(): string {
   return `http://example.com/${category.name.replace("&", "AND")}.png`;
}
```

Comment: A getter would be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes properly.

```
<img src="{{'http://example.com/'+category.name.replace(\"&\", \"AND\")+'.png'}}">
```